# Uniform convergence help

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Is this true ? please tell me how they got here, this is to prove the uniform convergence of the function (point wise limit is the function zero):

$$\text{for }x \in [0,\pi], \sup\left|\sin(x)^n\left(1-\sin(x)^n\right)\right|=\frac1{4^n}$$

Comment: What is $\sin(x)^n$? $\sin(x^n)$ or $(\sin(x))^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. Take $x=\arcsin\left(\sqrt[n]{\frac12}\right)$. Then$$\sin^n(x)\bigl(1-\sin^n(x)\bigr)=\frac14.$$

Comment: thank you ! that's what i got but i saw it in the textbook and i doubted my result

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: can you please tell me if the sequence converges uniformly ?

Comment: I can tell you that it **doesn't** converge uniformly, since it converges pointwise to the null function, but $\sup\bigl\lvert\sin^n(x)\bigl(1-\sin^n(x)\bigr)\bigr\rvert=\frac14$.